# How many bytes each fields of float(24,12) takes up in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I just want to know how many bytes each fileds of float(24,12) takes up of storage? What about (23,11)? How can I calculate it or how should I define M and D in float (M,D) so it takes upto 4 bytes at max?

Thanks in advance

Comment: According to docs, there is a non standard definition of float and double that sql supports. I am aware of that nine digits 4 bytes calculation, but at the other place it says float(23) takes 4 bytes.

Comment: @juergen d Pls read it here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html

Comment: The nine digits -> 4 bytes are for decimals (exact values), the 4/8 byte is for floats. These are significantly different, but you already found the place in the documentation to answer your question. Since you are already aware that using (m,d) is non-standard, be also aware that it will be removed in a future release, and also be aware that the values are indeed approximated. Please make sure that you really want to use this (and not e.g. decimal), there is basically no usecase for a float(m,d) compared to just using float.

Comment: @Abtin . . . You should probably be using `numeric`/`decimal` for these types.